# How to refresh/notify all sms apps and notification bar?

Tags: android, sms, refresh

I write sms messenger and have one problem. When user reads sms from my app and deletes them from my app, other apps and notification bar still show that one or more sms as unread. And when the user try to open sms, for example, from notification, other sms messenger didn't show unread sms beacause it was deleted from base from my app.

Is there any way to refresh sms apps and notification that would not show that sms not read?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do this. Furthermore it shouldn't be you job to care about this, it's the job of the other apps to show always the most current data.

But you can show some advised to the user when he starts your app for the first time. GO SMS for example advises the user to turn off the SMS notification of all other SMS applications on the device. I think the reason for this is similar to your issues.